# Современные нормы обращения людей друг к другу

Tags: грамотная-речь

Существуют ли сейчас хоть какие-то нормы обращений людей друг к другу? В официальных документах, насколько я знаю, это все-таки "господин/госпожа". А в обычной жизни? Как обращаться? Ибо хамское обращение "женщина/мужчина" оскорбляет просто до слез.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Норм, насколько я знаю, нет. Как обратиться? Смотря по ситуации. В публичных местах, слава Богу, теперь на бейджике написаны имя и отчество, к продавцу , например, так вполне уместно обратиться. А на улице - мне нравится обращение "сударыня" и "сударь". Именно так и обращались в досоветское время. Красивые слова почти уничтожили и попытались приучить к   безликому  "товарищ".

Answer (score 3):

Иногда можно услышать в качестве обращения "уважаемый (-ая)". Не очень? Но все лучше, чем "мужчина" и "женщина". Часто спасают эпитеты ("милые дамы!"). Вообще, в зависимости от ситуации можно найти способ, как обратиться. В крайнем случае, для привлечения внимания использовать приветствие ("здравствуйте!), а потом продолжить свое обращение (речь).

Comment: В городе на Неве часто слышу "дама". К мужчинам разного возраста обращение "молодой человек(!)"

Answer (score 1):

Это не по русскому языку вопрос, скорее по этикету. Причем не по речевому этикету, а общему, весьма косвенное к речевому имеющему.

Судя по упоминанию "мужчины" и "женщины" речь идёт об обращении к незнакомому человеку на улице или в общественном месте. Могу предложить набор слов, которые - в зависимости от пола и возраста адресата - могут помочь. **Уважаемый, сударь/сударыня, девушка, барышня, отец и т.д. вплоть до давно забытого "милостивый государь"**. Главное, чтобы объект был адекватен вообще и данному обращению в частности. А то в качестве аллаверды можно получить "ещё более адекватный" ответ.

Общего правила на все случаи жизни действительно нет. Но его нет и ни в одном языке. Даже в английском возможны варианты. разница в том, что в других языках есть возможность выбрать из нескольких вариантов нужный, а у нас выбирать в общем-то не из чего, приходится выкручиваться.

Comment: "аллаверды" - что это такое? В словарях нет. Или я не там искала?

Comment: "аллаверды" - что это такое? === http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords?layout=item&id=25_193

Answer (score 0):

Есть ведь еще и безличная форма обращения, например "Извините пожалуйста, сколько сейчас времени?". Ну, разумеется, такая форма уместна, когда тот, к кому вы обращаетесь, находится в непосредственной близости и видит вас.

Comment: 1. Ну есть такая "форма". От безвыходности. Вы предлагаете её узаконить?

Comment: 2. "Сколько времени" - само по себе вызывает вопросы. Безусловно правильная форма "Который час?".